# how to remove big space appear between main contents and footer in html & css?

Tags: html, css

I don't know why big space appearing between the main contents and footer? I thought it may be due to position:relative/absolute and replaced it with margin-top but still it doesn't solved. It really is taking my time please help..

Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
        <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Fri, 10 Jan 2014 11:20:23 GMT">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://www.your-website.com/css/6_dark_orange/css/www_rate_calc_frame.css" rel="stylesheet" title="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            #tmcmini
            {
                margin-left:-26px;
            }
        </style>
        <title>test</title>


        <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img src="images/logo.gif" />
                <h2>Asian Paradise Nepal</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="login">
                <h4>LOGIN&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; REGISTER</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="booking">
                <h4>online booking</h4>
            </div>

        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">company profile </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">destination </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">activities </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">tour packages </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="left">

                <div class="title">
                    <h5>Trip Search</h5>
                </div>
                <form action="search"> <li><select>
                            <option value="volvo">By Destination</option>
                            <option value="saab">By Activities</option>
                            <option value="opel">By Duration</option>
                            <option value="audi">By Price</option>
                        </select></li>
                    <li><select>

                            <option value="saab">By Activities</option>
                            <option value="opel">By Duration</option>
                            <option value="audi">By Price</option>
                        </select></li>
                    <li><select>
                            <option value="opel">By Duration</option>
                            <option value="audi">By Price</option>
                        </select></li>
                    <li><select>
                            <option value="audi">By Price</option>
                        </select></li>
                    <input type="image" src="images/srchbtn.jpg"> 
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="slide">
                <img src="img7.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="left">
                <div class="title">
                    <h5>Tour Package</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="left-content">
                    <li>Mountain Tour</li>
                    <li>Cultural Tour</li>
                    <li>Honeymoon Packages</li>
                    <li>Holidays Tour</li>
                    <li>Village Tour</li>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="left">
                <div class="title">
                    <h5>Testimonials</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="left-content">
                    It is very comfortable </br>to travel with Asian </br>Paradise Nepal.</br>John
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="left">
                <div class="title">
                    <h5>Destination</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="left-content">
                    <li>Nepal</li>
                    <li>India</li>
                    <li>Bhutan</li>
                    <li>Tibet</li>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="left">
                <div class="title">
                    <h5>Currency Exchange</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="left-content">
                    <iframe id="tmcmini" src="http://themoneyconverter.com/MoneyConverter.aspx?from=USD&amp;to=EUR" style="height: 210px; border: none; "  marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="-26px;" ></iframe>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right">
                <div class="title">
                    <h5>Activities</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="right-content">
                    <li>Mountain Tour</li>
                    <li>Cultural Tour</li>
                    <li>Honeymoon Packages</li>
                    <li>Holidays Tour</li>
                    <li>Village Tour</li>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right">
                <div class="title">
                    <h5>Activities</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="right-content">
                    <li>Mountain Tour</li>
                    <li>Cultural Tour</li>
                    <li>Honeymoon Packages</li>
                    <li>Holidays Tour</li>
                    <li>Village Tour</li>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right">
                <div class="title">
                    <h5>Activities</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="right-content">
                    <li>Mountain Tour</li>
                    <li>Cultural Tour</li>
                    <li>Honeymoon Packages</li>
                    <li>Holidays Tour</li>
                    <li>Village Tour</li>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right">
                <div class="title">
                    <h5>Nepal Information</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="right-content">
                    <li>Nepal@ glance</li>
                    <li>Passport & Visa</li>
                    <li>Money & exchange</li>
                    <li>Customs & Airport</li>
                    <li>Customs & Airport</li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="title">
                    <h5>Weather</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="right-content">
                    <span style="display: block !important;  text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><a href="http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=zmw:94114.1.99999&bannertypeclick=wu_bluestripes" title="San Francisco, California Weather Forecast" target="_blank"><img src="http://weathersticker.wunderground.com/weathersticker/cgi-bin/banner/ban/wxBanner?bannertype=wu_bluestripes&airportcode=KSFO&ForcedCity=San Francisco&ForcedState=CA&zip=94114&language=EN" alt="Find more about Weather in San Francisco, CA" width="100" /></a><br><a href="http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=zmw:94114.1.99999&bannertypeclick=wu_bluestripes" title="Get latest Weather Forecast updates" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px" target="_blank">Click for weather forecast</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="middle">
                <div class="welcome-msg">
                    <p>Welcome to the Asian paradise!
                        we are here to make your journey heavenly. we are here to make your journey heavenly.
                        we are here to make your journey heavenly.we are here to make your journey heavenly.we are here to make your journey heavenly.
                        we are here to make your journey heavenly.we are here to make your journey heavenly.we are here to make your journey heavenly.we are here to make your journey heavenly.we are here to make your journey heavenly.we are here to make your journey heavenly.we are here to make your journey heavenly.</p>
                </div>

                <h3>Featured Trip</h3>     
                <div class="featured-trip">          
                    <img src="images/pic.jpg">
                    <p class="desc">short description goes here.</p>       
                </div>

                <div class="featured-trip">                      
                    <img src="images/pic.jpg">
                    <p class="desc">short description goes here.</p>       
                </div>

                <div class="featured-trip">                 
                    <img src="images/pic.jpg">
                    <p class="desc">short description goes here.</p>       
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="footer-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">company profile </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">destination </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">activities </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">tour packages </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">contact </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="payment">
                    Payment:
                    <img src="mastercard.jpg" width="100" height="50">
                </div>
                <div class="follow-us">
                    Follow Us On:
                    <img src="facebook.png" width="32" height="32">
                    <img src="twitter.png" width="32" height="32">
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
header{
    background-color:#13dff2;
}
h2{
}
.login{
    background:url(images/ap_03.gif) no-repeat;
    border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    left: 1117px;
    position: relative;
    top: -137px;
}
.login h4{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:55px;
}
nav{
    background:url(images/ap_10.gif) repeat;
    height:34px;
}
nav ul{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding: 7px;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline;
}
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    color:black;
    padding-left:40px;
}
nav a:hover{
    background-color:#13dff2;
    background-position:right top;
    display:inline-block;
    height:35px;

}
.wrapper{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
/*.trip-search
{
    background:url(images/ap_25.gif) no-repeat;

}*/
.title{
    background:url(images/ap_13.gif) no-repeat;
    width: 182px;
}
.title h5{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;

    padding-left: 25px;
}
select{
    background-color:#f5f5f4;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    width: 121px;
}
.search{
    background:#13dff2;
    width:60px;

}
.search h5{
    padding:10px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
input{
    padding-left:40px;
}
.slide{
    /*left: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: -179px;*/
    float:right;
    margin-top:-179px;
}
.slide img{
    width:750px;
}
.left{
    background:url(images/ap_25.gif) no-repeat;
    /*position:relative;
    top:-249px;*/

}
/*.left-title
{
    background:url(images/ap_13.gif) no-repeat;
}*/
.left-content{
    margin-left:30px;

}
.right{
    background:url(images/ap_25.gif) no-repeat;

    /*left: 768px;
    position: relative;
    top: -715px;*/
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    top: -440px;
    clear:both;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
/*.right-title
{
    background:url(images/ap_13.gif) no-repeat;
}*/
.right-content{
    margin-left:30px;

}
.middle{
    float:left;
    margin-top: -993px;}
.welcome-msg{

    /* position: relative;*/
    text-align: justify;
    margin-right: 243px;
    padding-left: 209px;

}
/*  .title-trip
    {
    background:url(images/ap_13.gif) no-repeat;
    width: 182px;
    margin-left: 206px;
    }
    .title-trip h5
    {font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    padding-left:20px;}
*/
.featured-trip{
    /*background:url(images/dscbg.jpg) no-repeat;*/
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    /*left: 184px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1007px;*/
    margin: 6px 196px 19px;
    width: 529px;
    border:#EAEAEA 1px solid;
}
h3{
    background:url(images/ap_13.gif) no-repeat;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    margin: 23px 196px 3px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    /*position: relative;
    top: -998px;
    left: 190px;*/
}
.featured-trip img{
    /*width: 150px;*/
    height: 115px;
    /*margin-right: 10px;*/
    /*float: left;  */
}
.desc{margin: -32px 0 0 169px;
}
.footer{
    background:#f26c13;
}
.footer-menu ul li{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding: 7px;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}
.payment{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.follow-us{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:749px;}
img{
}
```

Comment: A link to the page would be useful

Comment: I am doing on localhost so how can i do that, to put link to page?

Comment: this is my test page and i am doing on localhost so how to give link?

Answer (score 0):

```
.middle
{
    float:left;
    margin-top: -993px;
}
```

Your problem is your `.middle` class. It got a margin-top of -993px.
Try to remove it completely (even the float:left;). It will work. When that graphical glitch will be fixed, look if it changes anything else

Comment: i removed the top margin and float:left but then whole middle part come downward and let space above...what can i do for that?

Comment: Man, I helped you fix that, then you should post a new question ;)
For that new problem, did you try fixing it? I can't do everything eh
Please accept my answer here, and create a new question. And if you still can't overcome it, I will consider giving you the answer

Comment: i did try and the problem is same just space moving up and down as top-margin removed and kept so why to post new? Also i didn't tell you to do everything just asking for next option and if you don't want to answer then its ok

Comment: That is another question, please accept my answer by clicking on the accept button x)
did you resolved your other question?